# How to create HTTP transactions graph from PCAP?

Tags: http, graph, pcap

I'd like to ask if there's a tool that creates an HTTP transactions graph (like on URLquery.net) out of PCAP file? I'd like to have nice visualisation of what redirections occured, what resources were downloaded etc.

Answer (score 1):

With Wireshark Graph Analyzer or tcptrace.

Example tcptrace (module HTTP):

[Analyze http traffic witch TCPtrace. Graph.](https://seguridadyredes.wordpress.com/2011/06/03/analizando-capturas-pcap-tcp-con-tcptrace-generacion-de-graficas-con-xplot-parte-4-avanzando/)

Best Regardas,

Comment: Thank you for a tip, I was rather thinking about a graph similar to what you can find in [URLquery](http://URLquery.net), with it's arrows and boxes.